# Which metric is used in this limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis(3rd ed) says on page 53 that 'If $\{p_n\}$ is a sequence in $X$ and if $E_N$ consists of the points $p_N,p_{N+1},p_{N+2},\dots$, it is clear from two preceding definitions (about Cauchy sequence and diameter) that $\{p_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence if and only if $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\text{diam } E_N=0$$'

Two preceding definitions:

1. A sequence $\{p_n\}$ in a metric space $X$ is said to be Cauchy sequence if for every $\epsilon>0$,there is an integer $N$ such that $d(p_n,p_m)<\epsilon$ if $n\ge N$ and $m\ge N$.

2.Let $E$ be a nonempty subset of a metric space $X$, and let $S$ be the set of all real numbers of the form $d(p,q)$, with $p\in E$ and $q\in E$ The sup of $S$ is called the diameter of $E$.

In $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\text{diam } E_N=0$, which metric is used? Is it 'absolute value' metric on $\Bbb R$ or any other metric on $\Bbb R$ will work?

Comment: For those of us who don't have access to the book, you may want to include the "two preceding definitions" in question, as well as that of $E_N$.

Comment: I am including it...

Comment: So, I guess the metric used is the one that comes with the metric space $X$.

Comment: @ClementC., but $X$ can be any metric space and not necessarily  $\Bbb R$, can any metric work on $\Bbb R$?

Comment: But there is no $\mathbb{R}$ mentioned anywhere. Why do you want a metric on $\mathbb{R}$? ($S$ is a set of real numbers obtained from the metric on $X$)

Comment: @ClementC.,the sequence $\{diam E_N\}$ is in $\Bbb R$, right?

Comment: Yes. But then, you use the usual definition of metric. For each $N$, you define a $S_N$ as a set of real numbers, using the metric on $X$. Then, you take the supremum of this set of real numbers, which is a value in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ -- and call it $s_N$ (this is $s_N=\textrm{diam} E_N$). Then you look at the limit of $s_N$. The only place an exotic metric is used is to define the set $S_N$.

Comment: Yes, the metric on $\mathbb R$ is used to say that the sequence $\operatorname{diam} E_n$ of real numbers converges to $0$ is the standard absolute value metric.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez, thank you very much, that is just what I wanted to know.

Comment: Rudin's  assertion is true regarding Cauchy sequences with respect to any metric d on any  set X. Although to be absolutely clear he or she should have said $E_N=\{p_j :j\geq N\}$. BTW is that Walter Rudin or Mary Ellen Rudin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metric is deliberately unspecified. Whatever metric $X$ is equipped with, the sequence is Cauchy with respect to that metric if and out if the diameter criterion holds with respect to that metric.

Put another way, for every metric space $(X,d)$, that theorem hold.

EDIT: if you want to know what metric is the limit being calculated with respect to, it's the normal one on $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be a metric space. $E\subset X$ has diameter $diam(E):= sup\;\{k \in \Bbb R | d(x,y) = r\; for \;x,y \in E\}$. Since $diam(E_N)$ is just a real number by definition, he means the usual absolute value metric.

To see the equivalence, notice that $diam(E_N) \rightarrow 0$ if and only if for all $ \varepsilon > 0$ there is $k \in \Bbb N$ sufficiently large such that $| sup\; \{d(p_i,p_j) | \;i, j \geq k\} | < \varepsilon$, but since the distances are non-negative by definition, we can omit the absolute value. You'll see this is exactly the definition of ${p_n}$ being Cauchy sequence in $X$. What you're doing is starting with a sequence (subset) of $X$, and for each $N$ pulling out a real number. This sequence of real numbers tends to zero if and only if the original sequence was Cauchy.